# Not able to bind data from local json to view polymer 2

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, iron-ajax

I am using Polymer 2 and want to bind data from a local json file. But each time I tried it it is not able to fetch the json file only.

There are 2 ways I have tried to achieve it with:

1) USING

```
<iron-ajax url="data/employees.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{items}}" auto>
</iron-ajax>
```

Folder Structure:

[image: folder Structure]

```
<iron-list items="{{items}}" as="item">
    <template>
        <div class="item">
            <b>[[item.nickname]]</b>
            <p>[[item.phone]]</p>
        </div>
    </template>
</iron-list>
```

I have also imported both iron-ajax and iron-list

2) USE `$.get` to extract data fron json in start and put it in a variable to bind it to view.

```
<script>
    class IronListClass extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {return 'iron-comp'}

        ready() {
            super.ready();
            var that = this;
            // $.get('data/employees.json', function(data) {
            //     that.employees = $.parseJSON(data).results;
            //     console.log(that.employees);
            // });
            $.get('data/employees.json', function(data) {
            this.employees = $.parseJSON(data).results;
            console.log(this.employees);
            }.bind(this));
        }        
    }
    window.customElements.define(IronListClass.is, IronListClass);
</script>
```

tried with that = this also.

Answer (score 0):

You may load the json file as follow example as its working at my app already.

```
   <iron-ajax 
            auto 
            url$="{{url}}" 
            handle-as="json" 
            last-response="{{loadedItems}}"
           >
    </iron-ajax>
```

...

```
     static get properties() { return { 
        url :{
            type:String,
            value() {return "./data/employees.json"; }
        }
```

...

```
    static get observers() { return ['checkJsonFileLoaded(loadedItems)']}

    checkJsonFileLoaded(j) {
       if (j) {
           this.set('items', j);
           console.log(items); //u should see the loaded json file. If so than the problem is iron-list (to publish the result)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for your help
Still not working can you help me figure out please

<iron-ajax url$="{{url}}" handle-as="json" last-response="{{items}}" auto></iron-ajax>

            static get properties() { return {
                    url: { type: String, value() {return "./data/employees.json"}
                    }
                }
            }

            static get observers() { 
          return ['checkJsonFileLoaded(items)']}
                checkJsonFileLoaded(j) {
                if (j) { this.set('items', j); console.log(items); }
            }
Gives 404

Comment: Seams you don't have json file at specified path. Check for path or file

Comment: I have provided the folder structure image above in main issue. Can you please provide an alternate path or see If I made a mistake.

Also in VSCode when I enter ./data it automatically suggests employee.json. What could be the problem?

Comment: JSON is in this format :-

[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum"
  }
]

Comment: Couldn't find the file. Please attach a full console message or link it as picture. Json format is not the subject yet. Just try to see any result at above console.log message